# Skip a particular color in smart invert mode of accessibility

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

Is there any way to skip a particular color in whole app when device is in **smart invert mode of accessibility**?

I don't want the blue color in my app to be inverted. I have am image which have black and blue color text in it. I want the black color text to be inverted but want to skip blue color.
Any help would be appreciated.

P.S -I am familiar with **accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors**. But this property can be applied on uiview or object but i need to skip a color.

Answer (score 0):

do it inside the appcolor constant file :- you can check UIAccessibilityIsInvertColorsEnabled() if its true then return clear color else reurn the blue color.

Comment: Where can i find this appcolor constant file ?

Comment: Also i have am image which have black and blue color text in it. I want the black color text to be inverted but want to skip blue color.